# Using average in query (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, average

I'm having trouble with coming up with a query to find the average age of the buses used for each bus company from the following schema:

buscompany

```
company_id | name
 1           NED
 2           JIM
```

bustype

```
type_id | date_made
 1        2006-01-26
 2        1999-05-05
 3        2000-09-01
```

route

```
route_id | bustype | bus_company
 1         2         1
 2         1         1
 3         1         1
 4         3         2
 5         3         2
 6         1         2
 7         2         2
```

In this example NED's average bus age is 4246.666 = 4247 days assuming today is 2013-03-18.

What would the whole query look like?

Answer (score 3):

I can't test right now, but something like:

```
-- assuming "date_made" is a pg DATE column
--
   SELECT buscompany.name, ROUND(AVG(CURRENT_DATE - date_made))
     FROM buscompany
LEFT JOIN route
          ON route.bus_company = buscompany.company_id
LEFT JOIN bustype
          ON route.bustype = bustype.type_id
 GROUP BY 1
```

ought to Do What You Want (tm).  Date subtraction in pg gives the difference in days.

Comment: @HalfFrench, how's that?  Again, cannot run against a live pg right now.

Comment: yeah that works. You've made such a simple query. I always over complicate mine and I still get them wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The following (based on a sample table I made) gave me the average in days.

```
select extract(day from avg(current_date-birthday)) from stuff;
```

avg gives you an interval and not the number of days, so I did the extract.

If you *want* to deal with the interval instead of a number of days then you can do this instead

```
select avg(age(birthday)) from stuff;
```

Comment: "birthday" must be a timestamp type for your `stuff`; coerce it to a date type and you will work with integers rather than intervals.

Comment: verified that if the column is of type date then the first statement does not need the extract statement. The second does still return an interval thanks to the `age` function. Thanks for pointing that out pilcrow. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2f53c/2